# Access has been blocked by CORS policy: despite setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: node.js, express, cors, render

I'm using render.com to host both the client and the server. I keep getting this error, despite the fact that I have configured cors to allow the origin that's being blocked.

The actual error:

```
video-streaming-client.onrender.com/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vid-ream-zrdw.onrender.com/status?uid=Y7Jnayw6fEaQWvE2w3vNiCQt7mu1' from origin 'https://vid-ream-client.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is what I have in my index.js file:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "https://vid-ream-client.onrender.com",
      "http://localhost:5173",
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

I also tried doing it my setting the headers using res.header

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://vid-ream-client.onrender.com"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  console.log("Request received:", req.method, req.url);

  next();
});
```

What am I missing here? The server works fine, when I got on it's url and query specifics routes, I get the appropriate response.

Comment: Which browser do you use?
I've found this Post regarding the same problem
https://community.render.com/t/no-access-control-allow-origin-header/12947/2

Comment: Hey @linusum Thanks for the reply. 

Yes I did take a look at that post, it doesn't solve the problem, I even tried to set cors to accept all origins, but for some reason that doesn't work either.

Just to note: I'm also using stripe, and the browser is throwing "failed to read a named property href from Location"... "Blocked a frame origin "stripe.com" from accessing a cross origin frame"

 I don't know if this has something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

If you encounter a similar error, where despite setting the headers to allow traffic from the client, the CORS error might not be the actual cause. In my case, I was facing a `502 Bad Gateway` error. After inspecting the logs on both my database and server, I discovered that some of the data types in my database were misconfigured as integers instead of strings.

The troubleshooting process took longer (2days) due to the following reasons:

1. **Bad Error Handling:**

   - I was only logging errors in my server without returning them to the client. This made it challenging to identify the root cause directly from the client-side.
2. **Failure to Check Database Logs:**

   - Despite deploying all three components (client, server, and database) to Render, I didn't anticipate my database logging errors. I assumed that my server would handle error logging, but it turned out that the database logs provided clear insights into the issue.

So to conclude, if you're getting a CORS error, and you exacerbated all the solutions you found online, it's likely that the cause of the CORS error is not actually CORS.